# What 80s or 90s sci-fi movie had an alien colosseum premise?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

What I remember is a human (blonde-haired ?), Flash Gordon-like protagonist dueling all manner of strange creatures, some considerably bigger than him, in some weird alien colosseum style arena. The fights were lethal. I remember a human female character as well, but not sure about her role. I think there was some technology involved, maybe ranged or weird mechanical weapons, and hand-to-hand combat. As with all childhood memories, I may be conflating multiple things into one, but I am quite sure about the basic "alien colosseum" premise. Can't seem to easily ID it.

And yes, Flash Gordon proper had a colosseum-style fight sequence, but this was something else - with a much darker, almost dystopian setting, weirder, creepier, larger creatures, etc. I think this was probably an 80's film, which aired in the 90s.

Comment: Live-action? Cartoon?

Comment: Live-action. @Sean Duggan

Comment: It's clearly not what you were remembering, but [Coneheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coneheads_(film)) (1993) has a climactic scene putting Beldar in peril in a weird alien colosseum arena.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could this be 1989's *[Arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arena_(1989_film))*?

> Lacking sufficient money for a ticket, Shorty attempts to raise the cash by gambling in an underground casino. The game is raided by the authorities and in the confusion, Shorty pockets the money. Caught in the act by crime boss Rogor (Marc Alaimo) and his enforcer Weezil (Armin Shimerman), Shorty is held for ransom. Steve promises to pay off the debt, so he reluctantly returns to Quinn and agrees to a contract. Remarkably he wins his first match with an alien named Sloth in an upset. He continues fighting, determined to prove that a human has what it takes to be champion, and soon becomes a top contender. Despite Rogor's multiple attempts to cheat, Steve ultimately wins the championship from Rogor's top fighter, an alien named Horn (Michael Deak).

[image: Movie poster] [image: Still image of blond protagonist]

Incidentally, [the female protagonist is likely Quinn](http://skippytheskeptic.blogspot.com/2015/02/arena-1989.html?_sm_au_=iVVKMDTFHMbDnnvP), his fight manager, who [later played Ivanona on *Babylon 5*](http://www.retroist.com/2014/08/20/arena-1989-the-b-movie-that-brings-the-retro-for-both-the-80s-and-the-90s/).

[image: Quinn, plucky female fight manager]

Comment: Yes, this got answered so quickly, the system won't even let me accept the answer yet. Surprised I remembered some of those details correctly, down to the blondish hair...

Comment: It's funny what sticks with you.

Comment: IIRC there is even a Babylon 5 Episode with a rather similar plot (although Ivanova is not involved - I think it's the episode where she sits shiva for her father).

Comment: @EikePierstorff: The only one I found with arena fighting is "All Alone in the Night" which introduced Ta'Lon, albeit as an unnamed mook.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - you may be thinking of the Tsunkatse episode from "Star Trek: Voyager".

Comment: Nope, I think about that episode where a human wants to prove he can compete with the alien fighters: http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/TKO

Comment: @EikePierstorff - ah, gotcha. Been a loooong time since I've seen that one.